# passing my function to useeffect crashes my app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Hi Im trying to implement openpay services to my react native app but when i try to generate the TokenID from the credit card info i got problems with the use effect

this is the code

```
 useEffect(() => {
let isCancelled = false;
if (vCardNameOwner && vCardNumber && vCardExpirationMonth && vCardExpirationYears && vCardCVV) {
openpay.createCardToken({
    holder_name: vCardNameOwner,
    card_number: vCardNumber,
    expiration_month: vCardExpirationMonth,
    expiration_year: vCardExpirationYears,
    cvv2: vCardCVV,
   })
      .then((token) => setvTokenId(token), console.log( '/////generacion de token//////' ,token));
    }
      return () => {
        isCancelled = true;
      };
  }, [vCardNameOwner, vCardNumber, vCardExpirationMonth, vCardExpirationYears, vCardCVV]);
```

that code makes my app to crash because token isnt declared and i dont know how to re do the operation so it can work fine

if i delete the useeffect thing and leave just the openpay function with hardcoded values everything work well but i need it to take the values that the user insert in the form

```
 openpay.createCardToken({
    holder_name: vCardNameOwner,
    card_number: vCardNumber,
    expiration_month: vCardExpirationMonth,
    expiration_year: vCardExpirationYears,
    cvv2: vCardCVV,
  })
  .then((token) => setvTokenId(token), console.log( '/////generacion de token//////' ,token));
```

thanks a lot for your time

Comment: Which token is not declared? What line crashes this exactly?

Comment: this one 
.then((token) => setvTokenId(token), console.log( '/////generacion de token//////' ,token));

Comment: this is the error on console ReferenceError: Can't find variable: token

Comment: Can you just log it before setting it to the state? just log the `token`, what does it give you?

Comment: anything, it seems that the line console.log( '/////generacion de token//////' ,token) doesnt do anything in the use effect

Comment: Just replace this .then((token) =>{ setvTokenId(token);console.log( '/////generacion de token//////' ,token));} instead of this .then((token) => setvTokenId(token), console.log( '/////generacion de token//////' ,token));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a syntax error.

This will trigger an error as it is not in the instruction block

```js
, console.log( '/////generacion de token//////' ,token)
```

If you just want to console log the token, you can do it like this.

```js
openpay.createCardToken({
    holder_name: vCardNameOwner,
    card_number: vCardNumber,
    expiration_month: vCardExpirationMonth,
    expiration_year: vCardExpirationYears,
    cvv2: vCardCVV,
  })
  .then((token) => console.log( '/////generacion de token//////' ,token) || setvTokenId(token));
```